# Regular expression which does not match specific string

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a regular expression which would match everything, except a specific string. I have found a lot of examples which check if it contains a string, but I need it to be exact. So if the string is `example`:

- `example` → does not match
- `whatever` → matches
- `aexample` → matches
- `examplea` → matches

Comment: I think it's possible when your words are in separate lines... by : `/^(?!example)$/`

Comment: `^(?!example$)` / `^(?!example$).*`

Comment: why don't you match "example" and negate the result outside the regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I have no control of the matching code (sort of), I just can provide regex.